# Dataframe - assign values to corresponding indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column of values to the existing data frame by assigning values to corresponding indexes.

This is my data frame `df`

```
     ID
 0   A    
 1   B 
 2   C
```

I want to append the `Value` column to it, where

```
values = [2, 5]
indexes = [1, 2]
```

So the new data frame should look like this:

```
     ID Value
 0   A    
 1   B   2
 2   C   5
```

How should I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using `loc`

```
df.loc[indexes , 'Value'] = values
df


    ID  Value
0   A   NaN
1   B   2.0
2   C   5.0
```

Comment: Very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'Value': values}, index=indexes), 
         left_index=True, 
         right_index=True, 
         how='left')
```

you could create a dataframe from `values` & `index` merge it to the original dataframe, essentially doing a left join.

Alternatively, using combine first, it is even shorter to write

```
df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame({'Value': values}, index=indexes))
```